# useState retorna 2 arrays, como faço para pegar o array com o conteúdo, sendo que esta vazio?

Tags: react, react-hooks

Aqui está meu código

```
var [slideCategory, setSlideCategory] = useState([])
  
  
  async function getFiles() {
    const load = new LoadFile()
    
    await load.loadFiles()
    .then((res) => { 
      
      setSlideCategory([res])
      
      
     })
    .catch((err) => { console.log(err) })
  };
  
  
  useEffect(() => {
    getFiles()
    
  }, []);
  
  
  console.log(slideCategory)
```

quando excuto a função e alimento a minha variavel com o retorno da função, ele grava dois arrays diferentes, um vazio do proprio useStatee um com as informações que eu quero.